# Filtering a DataSet using Select NOT LIKE (ASP.net 2 Webforms)

Tags: dataset, c#-2.0, webforms

I'm trying to query a dataset from a stored-procedure but I'm making a mess somewhere..

```
specials.DataSource = ds.Tables["specials"].Select("mycolumnname NOT Like 'BB'%");
```

Any ideas whats wrong with the above statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percent symbol in the wrong place

```
specials.DataSource = ds.Tables["specials"].Select("mycolumnname NOT Like 'BB'%");
```

should be

```
specials.DataSource = ds.Tables["specials"].Select("mycolumnname NOT Like 'BB%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to include the percent sign inside the single quotes:

```
.Select("mycolumnname NOT Like 'BB%'");
```